# question about 4500x enterprise license

Tags: cisco

i have a cisco 4500x switch and here is the license output :

```
Switch#show lic all
License Store: Primary License Storage
StoreIndex: 0 Feature: entservices  Version: 1.0
      License Type: Permanent
      License State: Active, In Use
      License Count: Non-Counted
      License Priority: Medium
License Store: Dynamic License Storage
License Store: Primary License Storage
License Store: Dynamic License Storage
StoreIndex: 0 Feature: entservices  Version: 1.0
      License Type: Evaluation
        Evaluation total period: 8 weeks 4 days
        Evaluation period left: 8 weeks 4 days
      License State: Inactive
      License Count: Non-Counted
      License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 1 Feature: entservices  Version: 1.0
      License Type: PermanentRightToUse
      License State: Inactive
      License Count: Non-Counted
StoreIndex: 2 Feature: ipbase  Version: 1.0
      License Type: Evaluation
        Evaluation total period: 8 weeks 4 days
        Evaluation period left: 8 weeks 4 days
      License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
      License Count: Non-Counted
      License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 3 Feature: ipbase  Version: 1.0
      License Type: PermanentRightToUse
      License State: Inactive
      License Count: Non-Counted
StoreIndex: 4 Feature: lanbase  Version: 1.0
      License Type: PermanentRightToUse
      License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
      License Count: Non-Counted
```

i want to make sure it has permanent enterprise license, and it seems has a lifetime permanent enterprise license right? i think this true because it has the following options in the license output

```
StoreIndex: 0 Feature: entservices  Version: 1.0
      License Type: Permanent
      License State: Active, In Use
      License Count: Non-Counted
      License Priority: Medium
```

but what are the following options in the license :

```
  License Type: Evaluation
    Evaluation total period: 8 weeks 4 days
    Evaluation period left: 8 weeks 4 days
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you rebooted your 4500X after license activation? But you are right, you can use `entservices` without any restrictions.

For more info please check or you should send output from this commands:

`show license right-to-use
show license right-to-use detail`

Comment: yes i have reboot it, but i think it has lifetime activation, as i can see the following :StoreIndex: 0 Feature: entservices  Version: 1.0
      License Type: Permanent
      License State: Active, In Use
      License Count: Non-Counted
      License Priority: Medium, does not it?

Comment: Yes, its lifetime. In `show version` you can also see your License Level. There is multiple commands, the best for verification (from my POV) is `show license in-use`.